# Error in displaying sweet alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm trying to make an alert using the [Sweet Alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) library.
I have tried to integrate the code for making a confirmation alert for deleting an item, but when I click on the button for deleting the item these not work. The dialog is not displayed.

Code **before** integrating Sweet Alert:

```
$(".delete-link").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var del_id = id;
    var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
    if (confirm('Sure to Delete ID no = ' + del_id)) {
        $.post('delete.php', { 'del_id': del_id }, function(data) {
            parent.fadeOut('slow');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Code **after** integrating Sweet Alert:

```
    $(".delete-link").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var del_id = id;
        var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
    });

    swal({
            title: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
            text: "Sure to Delete ID no = " + del_id,
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function() {
            $.post('delete.php', { 'del_id': del_id }, function(data) {
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: no i thibk there is a problem with the code but i don't now where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a syntax error in your code. Try this, see if it works [I HAVE NOT TESTED THE CODE ON MY SIDE]. If it does not work, let me know

```
$(".delete-link").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var del_id = id;
var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");

swal({
    title: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
    text: "Sure to Delete ID no = " + del_id,
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No",
    closeOnConfirm: true,
    closeOnCancel: true
}, function(isConfirm) {
    $.post('delete.php', {'del_id':del_id}, function(data) {
        parent.fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
return false;
});
```